# Converting JSON array in JSON object to array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to convert the following json:

```
{
    "questions": [
        {
            "question#1": "How much is 3+1",
            "correct answer": 1,
            "answers": {
                "ans#1": "5",
                "ans#2": "4",
                "ans#3": "3"
            }
        },
 {
            "question#5": "How much is 2+4",
            "correct answer": 0,
            "answers": {
                "ans#1": "6",
                "ans#2": "4",
                "ans#3": "7",
                "ans#4": "5"
            }
        }

    ]
}
```

by using the following code in Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("data.json", function(json) {
        console.log(json); // this will show the info it in firebug console
       var sarit = Object.keys(json); // "a"

    });

    /*var update = document.getElementById("content");
    update.innerHTML("test");*/

    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML =  JSON.stringify(sarit);
});
```

I got an error-Uncaught ReferenceError: sarit is not defined

How can I get the answers' value of each question, and use it in the html file, aka content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sarit` doesn't exist when `document.getElementById("content").innerHTML =  JSON.stringify(sarit);` is called and it isn't in the scope so couldn't be seen even if it was try this instead.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("data.json", function(json) {
        console.log(json); // this will show the info it in firebug console
        var sarit = Object.keys(json); // "a"
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML =  JSON.stringify(sarit);
    });
});
```

That said his will only get you `["questions"]` displayed in your html page. In order to get the answers value you have to traverse the json to retrieve the values like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("data.json", function(json) {
        var anserFor1st = json.questions[0].answers;
        var anserFor2nd = json.questions[1].answers;//If it's more than two use a loop
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML =  JSON.stringify(anserFor1st) + "<br/>" + JSON.stringify(anserFor2nd);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you it's working now! The problem is that the answers are presented like this {"ans#1":"5","ans#2":"4","ans#3":"3"}
{"ans#1":"20","ans#2":"10","ans#3":"16","ans#4":"12","ans#5":"14","ans#6":"18"}   my attention is only display the value (the answers themselves)

Comment: If you want to only display the answers themselves loop through the answers to create a string and then display them e.g.


`var aString = "";`

`Object.keys(anserFor1st).forEach(function (k) {aString += anserFor1st[k] + "<br/>";});`

`Object.keys(anserFor2nd).forEach(function (k) {aString += anserFor2nd[k] + "<br/>";});`

`document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = aString;`

Also it's polite to accept an answer if you think it's correct :)

Comment: I didn't know about the "accept". I would  gladly accept it if I knew how to.... How I do it?

Comment: Click the checkmark under this post, on the left. (I think it's right below the arrows).

See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Comment: I accepted it:) 10x again!  One last question: How I'm supposed to push the values dynamically . I should build JS multi select questionnaire.. so I need to display the values of the different question dynamically... I have to move between questions by back and forward buttons.

Comment: Thanks, you should look at the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onhashchange in regards the forward and back button. The other option is to look into the jquery solution to browser history to help you on your way http://plugins.jquery.com/history/

Comment: my issue is not with the buttons. I just want to know how to  display the values of the different question dynamically (I don't want to display all of the questions together).

Answer (score 1):

The scope of `sarit` is the succeed handler for `getJSON`, it doesn't exist outside.

Also, take into account that `getJSON` runs async so having a statement inmediatly after a call to this method depending on the response is wrong. The the ajax call won't be finished by the time next line is executed.